# The right way to create a config.php

Tags: php, security, include, config

At the moment I am placing my config.php file in the `include folder`  on my Apache Server, which gives me easy access to the file, with having to write a directory path. I assume this is a good idea since it is secure and not reachable from outside the public root folder.

I was never told how to create the `config.php` file so I improvised, but it seems to that it may have been done the wrong way.. (not that secure now). Then I began to search for tutorials on how to build these config files the right way, but each and every tutorial had their own way to do it.. Some did it by using arrays.. some did it by defining the configuration variables.. others by using a class.. There may not be a right way, but I want a secure and very functional system to work, and I don't really care how advanced it is going to be..

This is my current config file.. you should easily see that it is not that secure in any way, cause anybody might just be able to echo the variables and then read the connection.

```
<?
$main_host = 'db01.server.local'; // There may be db02, db03 etc.
$main_psw = '********';
$main_host_end = '.server.local'; // makes it possible for me to connect to a different datastore only knowing the subdomain.

// ***    USERS    *** //
$w_user = 'w_user';
$xr_user = 'xr_user';
$r_user = 'r_user';
$w_server = 'w_server';
$w_db_admin = 'dbw_admin';

// ***    DATABASES    *** //
$db_accounts = 'accounts';
$db_server = 'server_setup';

// ***    DB ACCOUNTS    *** //
try {
    $w_accounts = new PDO("mysql:host=$main_host;dbname=$db_accounts", $w_user, $main_psw);
    $w_accounts->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $r_accounts = new PDO("mysql:host=$main_host;dbname=$db_accounts", $r_user, $main_psw);
    $r_accounts->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// ***    DB SERVER SETUP    *** //
try {
    $w_server = new PDO("mysql:host=$main_host;dbname=$db_server", $w_user, $main_psw);
    $w_server->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $r_server = new PDO("mysql:host=$main_host;dbname=$db_server", $r_user, $main_psw);
    $r_server->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

So.. to ask the question directly. What is the right way to create a config.php file? I really also hope that other people will find this useful to know.

**EDIT** I also should mension that this might not be all.. I may have further connections to make.. not only the `accounts` and `server_setup`

Comment: A config file should only contain settings for your enviroment. So I would move the database creation out of it.

Comment: The reason I made it like this, is because I don't want helping programmers to know whats in the config file.. But I guess that it is maybe impossible to secure that way?

Answer (score 0):

First, never ever echo exception messages in production, instead put them into a readable logfile.

If You look at many MVC frameworks, their php config files only consist of an array, that is returned at the end of the file.

Limiting access to these config files can be done via .htaccess with "Deny from all"

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is writing code in your project whom you don't trust, anyway you're in big trouble. So echoing variables is must not be a concern. So your only concern is how to secure your PHP configs from someone accessing them through  web browser.
For that I would suggest putting all your config files into `configs/` directory and adding `.htaccess` file with following content:

```
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch .*\.php$>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```